# The output of du -sh /tmp is much greater than the sum of du on each file and directory in /tmp. Why?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, tmp

This system is linux mint 18.3, basically ubuntu.

`sudo du --apparent-size -sb /tmp` yields **476mb** on my system currently.

if I run `sudo du --apparent-size -sb /tmp/* /tmp/.??*` and add it all up, I get about **4mb**.

(I know -b includes --apparent-size, just want to be explicit for this question)

Actually, to find the sum since I'm lazy, so I ran:

`sudo du --apparent-size -sb /tmp/* /tmp/.??* | cut -f 1 | paste -sd+ - | bc`

Why the difference?  Are there some hidden files in /tmp that du isn't finding, or is there a mistake in my commands?

edit:  despite my poor `.??*` to catch .dirs and .files, there were no .a, .b, .c etc files in this case.

Comment: Possibility: you have large files names `.a`, `.b`, etc. (`.` with single character after it)?

Comment: This is not a duplicate, because the OP is using **THE SAME TOOL** to measure **THE SAME FILES**, whereas the possible duplicates compare the outputs of different tools and/or different copies of a file. The comment/answer by @muru is a distinct possibility in this scenario, but never in the possible duplicates.

Comment: @muru - I looked to see if there were .a etc that .??* would miss - no, there weren't.

Answer (score 4):

One way to reproduce this case is to create lots of empty files (ideally of long filename length) which will expand the size of the directory (`.`) where the filenames are stored but not the size of the files (and `*` does not match the directory where those filenames are stored):

```
% mkdir emptydir && cd emptydir
% du --apparent-size -sb .
6       .
% du --apparent-size -sb * | cut -f 1 | paste -sd+ - | bc
zsh: no matches found: *
% jot 100000 | while read n; do touch $n; done
% du --apparent-size -sb .
2359296 .
% du --apparent-size -sb * | cut -f 1 | paste -sd+ - | bc
0
```

So we've here taken the empty directory from 6 to 2359296 while the glob version still totals zero because the files created are all empty.